# Check json array has any item

Tags: java, arrays

My program is to get a list of Java objects from the "result" string derived from the AsyncTask. In order to do so, I need to use JsonParser to get an JsonArray. In case the "result" string is [], the JsonArray is also []. How can I detect if there is any item in this Json array. I've tried all of suggestions, even detected at the "result" string, nothing is working for me, could you please help? My JsonArray: []

```
    try{
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(orderList).getAsJsonArray();
        System.out.println("Inside fromJasonToJava, array: " + array); //This prints out array: []
        lst =  new ArrayList<Order>();
        if(array.get(0)!= null) { //It goes wrong here, I need a working "if" condition
            //Value is not null
            for (final JsonElement json : array) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(json));
                                    System.out.println("Inside fromJasonToJava, jsonObject:" + jsonObject);

            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new Exception("Convert json to java error [fromJasonToJava()]", e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your if check for size instead, if you are using `org.json.simple.JSONArray`

```
if(array.size() != 0)
```

or if you using `org.json.JSONArray`

```
if(array.length() != 0)
```

Comment: I tried all of these before posting the question, non works.

Answer (score 0):

You may use if(array.length() > 0)

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use the if condition as java's for-each is smart enough to handle this.

If the array doesn't have any vale or it's empty then it will not get executed at all.

So use this code:

```
for (final JsonElement json : array) { // it will not get executed at all if array is empty
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(json));
                                System.out.println("Inside fromJasonToJava, jsonObject:" + jsonObject);
```

Instead of

```
    if(array.get(0)!= null) { //It goes wrong here, I need a working "if" condition
        //Value is not null
        for (final JsonElement json : array) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(json));
                                System.out.println("Inside fromJasonToJava, jsonObject:" + jsonObject);

        }
```

Comment: Yea, I hadn't had any if condition before, it threw exception when my JsonArray is []. Then I figured I need to add the if :-). I've tried all suggestions in stackoverflow, size()!=0, >0, keys().next!=null, blah blah... There was an idea to use jquery but I don't want to apply any new technique for just a simple issue like this one, hmm. simple